# The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to implement Repository with delete query.

```
@Repository
public interface LogRepository extends JpaRepository<Log, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Log> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from " + Log.class.getName() + " r where r.createdAt <= ?1") 
    int deleteByCreatedAt(LocalDateTime createdAt);
}
```

But I get error `The value for annotation attribute Query.value must be a constant expression`

Is there some way to implement this?

Comment: No you can't, Why not fix the name of the table name because you are using JPA so don't afraid that will cause problems

Answer (score 2):

The query `"delete from " + Log.class.getName() + " r where r.createdAt <= ?1"` is not constant indeed, as it will change with the change of the `Log` class. But why would you want to keep this dynamic? Is not like you will change the table name in the database very often. Just define it statically and you will be good to go.

Comment: This, plus if you're really worried about renaming, just use `#{#entityName}` instead of a hardcoded value